# I want open the file (YR2013.accdb) using shell function from the current database I'm using

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want open an accdb file (YR2013.accdb) by using shell function. I have tried the code below

```vb
Private Sub Command10_Click()
  shell "MSAccess C:\Users\ABUL ABAS\Desktop\YR2013.accdb"
End sub
```

But it only opens the Access App, telling me that it cannot recognize the path of the file.

Comment: Path contains blanks, so it has to be quoted (blanks indicate the next parameter of msaccess.exe). Try`shell "MSAccess ""C:\Users\ABUL ABAS\Desktop\YR2013.accdb"""`(the doubled double-quote escapes the double-quote in strings).

Comment: Thank you for you help, but it tells me that; file not found

Comment: What means wrong path! Insert`C:\Users\ABUL ABAS\Desktop\YR2013.accdb`into explorers address bar to be sure. Then open files properties and check path and name!

Comment: Thank you  very much sir, I have got all what I want with that explorers and it works perfectly.